# Problem install lift framework on Fedora

Tags: scala, lift, sbt

I'm trying to start the lift_basic project from the latest version of lift (2.4-M1).

I'm following the docs - untarred the tarball, then changed into `scala_29/lift_basic` and ran `./sbt update` but it fails with:

```
Getting Scala 2.7.7 ...
:: retrieving :: org.scala-tools.sbt#boot-scala
confs: [default]
2 artifacts copied, 0 already retrieved (9911kB/112ms)
Getting org.scala-tools.sbt sbt_2.7.7 0.7.5 ...
:: retrieving :: org.scala-tools.sbt#boot-app
confs: [default]
16 artifacts copied, 0 already retrieved (4271kB/107ms)
[info] Recompiling project definition...
[info]    Source analysis: 1 new/modified, 0 indirectly invalidated, 0 removed.
sbt.UndefinedValue: Value for property '<unnamed>' from /var/www/html/projects/lift/lift-lift_24_sbt-14a1743/scala_29/lift_basic/project/build.properties is undefined.
at sbt.BasicEnvironment$UserProperty.sbt$BasicEnvironment$UserProperty$$inheritedValue(Environment.scala:155)
at sbt.BasicEnvironment$UserProperty$$anonfun$resolveDefaultFirst$1.apply(Environment.scala:135)
at sbt.BasicEnvironment$UserProperty$$anonfun$resolveDefaultFirst$1.apply(Environment.scala:135)
at sbt.BasicEnvironment$UserProperty.sbt$BasicEnvironment$UserProperty$$getDefault(Environment.scala:143)
at sbt.BasicEnvironment$UserProperty.resolveDefaultFirst(Environment.scala:135)
at sbt.BasicEnvironment$UserProperty.resolve(Environment.scala:120)
at sbt.Environment$Property.value(Environment.scala:16)
at LiftProject.<init>(LiftProject.scala:4)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
at sbt.Project$.constructProject(Project.scala:391)
at sbt.Project$$anonfun$9.apply(Project.scala:365)
at sbt.Project$$anonfun$9.apply(Project.scala:364)
at scala.Either$RightProjection.map(Either.scala:239)
at sbt.Project$.loadProject(Project.scala:364)
at sbt.Project$.loadProject(Project.scala:355)
at sbt.Project$.loadProject(Project.scala:343)
at sbt.Project$.loadProject(Project.scala:340)
at sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:47)
at sbt.xMain.run0$1(Main.scala:35)
at sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:42)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:53)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$explicit$1.apply(Launch.scala:42)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$explicit$1.apply(Launch.scala:42)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:57)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$.explicit(Launch.scala:42)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$.initialized(Launch.scala:38)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$.parsed(Launch.scala:31)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$.configured(Launch.scala:21)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:16)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:13)
at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:24)
at xsbt.boot.Boot$.run(Boot.scala:19)
at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:15)
at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
Error loading project: sbt.UndefinedValue: Value for property '<unnamed>' from /var/www/html/projects/lift/lift-lift_24_sbt-14a1743/scala_29/lift_basic/project/build.properties is undefined.
```

Does anyone know where I'm going wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried this out myself (on Ubuntu 10.04) and I'm getting the exact same error.  It's attempting to get a build configuration property and for some reason failing.  I don't know enough about the SBT internals to offer a full solution, but I can show you how to get around it for now.

Simply open up the project/build/LiftProject.scala and on line 4, change

```
val liftVersion = property[Version].value.toString
```

to

```
val liftVersion = "2.4-M3" //use the value in project/build.properties for lift.version
```

After I did this, SBT was able to update and the example project compiled and ran without error.